# Vuetify-loader together with markdown loader

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, webpack-loader, vuetify-loader

I have a project built with vuetify-loader for treeshaking which is working fine. I wanted to add a markdown loader like [vue-markdown-loader](https://github.com/QingWei-Li/vue-markdown-loader) or [vmark-loader](https://github.com/egoist/vmark-loader) so I added this to webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.md$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'vue-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'vue-markdown-loader/lib/markdown-compiler',
          options: {
            raw: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But now vuetify-loader stopped working. It basically not loading any components.
I'm guessing it has something to do with the `vue-loader` being used but I really know nothing about webpack loaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update vuetify-loader to v1.6.0, I just released a fix for that yesterday: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/releases/tag/v1.6.0